# How can I accept an user input and match it with an excel column containing the same text string

Tags: python, excel, pandas, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a program that reads an excel file containing some data, asks the user for an input, and if the input entered matches with a cell, for the cell to get highlighted. This code currently works well for cells containing integer values as I can use arithmetic operators to calculate desired results and add them to a newly created column, however if I wanted to compare and match an entered string input to an existing string in a cell, and specifically color that cell only, what changes can I make? I'm a bit new at this and can't seem to find any solution on google for this

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx") 
df  #show the data

margin_threshold=0.9 

df['Column3'] = df['Column1']/df['Column2']

df.style.apply(lambda x:['background:red' if x < margin_threshold else 
'background:green' for x in df.Column3],axis=0)
```

Comment: if `df['Column1']` and `df['Column2']` are still integer inside but stores as string, you can modified your code as `df['Column3'] = float(df['Column1'])/float(df['Column2'])` to save your result to `df['Column3']`.

Comment: Thank you for that! However if    df['Column1'] and    df['Column2'] contained only strings, What would be the way to match input to the cells containing the same input?

Comment: What does `the same input` look like? Could you give an example?